# Why have certain characters disappeared?

Tags: kaobook

Without having changed anything in my LaTeX installation, certain characters have disappeared. (I use pdflatex to compile file).

For example, the + is no longer displayed in math mode.

Here is an example :

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=10pt, 
    twoside=true]{kaobook}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % Load characters and hyphenation

%%%% A DECOMMENTER POUR AVOIR LES PUCES VOULUES %%%%
%\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

% Load mathematical packages for theorems and related environments
\usepackage{kaotheorems}

% Load the package for hyperreferences
\usepackage{kaorefs}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter % Denotes the start of the main document content, resets page numbering and uses arabic 

\setchapterstyle{kao}
\setcounter{margintocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}
\marginlayout

N'affiche pas le + : $1+1$.

\begin{itemize}
\item test 1
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Additionally, if I uncomment `\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}` compilation fails.

I tried to update miktex.

How can I find my + and my bullets ?

Comment: kaotheorems.sty and kaorefs.sty are not in texlive, this I assume? https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{newpx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
N'affiche pas le + : $1+1$.
\end{document}`

Comment: do not load lmodern. That clashes with newpx loaded by the class.

Comment: The class (actually the `kao.sty` package) is quite inflexible and uses Libertinus with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and, for strange reasons, `newpx` with `pdflatex`, offering no option for disabling the choice. So if you later load `lmodern` you have to expect problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kaobook` class is quite inflexible in the choice of fonts. It will use Libertinus with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and NewPX with `pdflatex` (I'm not sure why different fonts).

If you really want to use `lmodern` with the class, you can trick it into thinking that `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` have already been loaded.

```
%%% trick kaobook into not loading NewPX
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@newpxtext.sty}{}
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{opt@newpxtext.sty}{scaled=.97,helvratio=.93,p,theoremfont}
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@newpxmath.sty}{}
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{opt@newpxmath.sty}{vvarbb,smallerops,bigdelims}
%%% end of hack

\documentclass[
    fontsize=10pt, 
    twoside=true]{kaobook}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % Load characters and hyphenation

%%%% A DECOMMENTER POUR AVOIR LES PUCES VOULUES %%%%
%\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

% Load mathematical packages for theorems and related environments
\usepackage{kaotheorems}

% Load the package for hyperreferences
\usepackage{kaorefs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}% <--- don't forget

\begin{document}

\mainmatter % Denotes the start of the main document content, resets page numbering and uses arabic 

\setchapterstyle{kao}
\setcounter{margintocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}
\marginlayout

N'affiche pas le + : $1+1$.

\begin{itemize}
\item test 1
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]